# Will the irobot create library work with other roomba models?

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

I have a roomba 595. I connected it to my Pi via serial but I'm having a tough time finding commands or documentation for it. I was wondering if the same commands used for the create model roombas would work for non-create models.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same commands for the Create2 will work with a Roomba 595.